# Реализация многопоточного select()

Tags: c++

Есть задача: сделать кроссплатформенный `epoll` на основе `select`. Она была решена, но оказалось, что можно сделать еще лучше.

Сейчас схема такая: В одном потоке крутится `select()`, обрабатывая список подключенных сокетов. При обнаружении готового к работе сокета он помещается в список. Еще в нескольких потоках крутятся функции, постоянно опрашивающие список сокетов. Опрос в виде:

```
socket_data *d; while(!(d=work_buf.read())) Sleep(1);
```

Подскажите, как реализовать механизм в котором функция будет зависать, пока нет новых данных. Говорят для решения этой задачи стоит использовать conditional variables, к сожалению я пока с ними не работал. Правильно ли я понимаю, что они в принципе состоят из двух функций? Одна позволяет потоку заснуть, а вторая его будит (`pthread_cond_wait()` и `pthread_cond_signal()`).

Хмм, кажется к концу вопроса я понимаю, что conditional variables именно то, что мне нужно. Есть ли подводные камни в использовании conditional variables? Я буду использовать их под windows, linux и андроид. Пока из проблем я вижу, что может проснуться больше одного потока.

Comment: К отличному ответу от @Pavel Mayorov могу только добавить практический совет -- для реализации кроссплатформенности побольше  используйте ifdef-ы, тогда, возможно, сможете вообще избежать многопоточности для реализации *низкоуровневых* вызовов.

Answer (score 6):

`epoll` на основе `select` - это плохая идея хотя бы потому что от `epoll` ожидается скорость работы, которую невозможно достичь используя `select`.

Если же под `epoll` вы понимаете всего-навсего работу с множеством неблокирующих сокетов - то да, имеет смысл использовать условные переменные. Если не найдете способ лучше.

Сейчас вам надо раздать работу нескольким потокам, верно? Такая задача называется "Producer - Consumer problem". Существуют проверенные алгоритмы и структуры данных, ее решающие. Их можно найти в гугле.

В данном случае, требуемая структура данных называется "блокирующая очередь" - и она является основным атомом для так называемой "безопасной" многопоточности (многопоточности без разделяемых данных). Возможно, вам стоило бы поискать в гугле реализацию блокирующей очереди через `pthreads`.

Но есть способ еще проще. Зачем вообще одному потоку слушать сокеты, раздавая затем другим потокам задачи на чтение? Почему бы не разрешить каждому потоку делать вызов `select`, чтобы найти себе очередной кусок работы?

Получается довольно простой алгоритм:

```
1. зайти в критическую секцию;
2. проверить список сокетов;
2.1. если список пуст - выполнить `select` и сложить все сокеты в список;
3. достать из списка сокет;
4. выйти из критической секции;
5. обработать сокет.
```

Но, скажите, сколько вообще у вас будет сокетов? Смущает меня такой подход к сетевому взаимодействию при наличии Андроида в списке платформ. Небольшое число подключений - до 1000 - прекрасно держится на одном ядре, не нуждаясь в многопоточной обработке в принципе. Заодно это освободит остальные ядра для UI - что весьма актуально для того же Андроида.

И последний вопрос. Вы вообще рассматривали `boost::asio` в качестве пригодной для работы библиотеки? Там уже все реализовано...

Comment: Я дописал свою реализацию epoll на селектах, она зажигает так, что на тестах обгоняла epoll. А с epoll возникли проблемы: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/

Comment: Значит, вы что-то делали неправильно.

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что написал неправильную реализацию, но к сожалению пока не могу понять где ошибка: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426786/