# Многопоточный epoll

Tags: c++, linux, g++, epoll

Написал код с `epoll_create1(0); epoll_ctl(); epoll_wait();` и при вызове `epoll_wait();` из двух потоков с удивлением вижу, что они возвращают одинаковые сокеты.

Мне казалось, что epoll можно использовать из разных потоков. Я не прав? Как получить многопоточный epoll? Есть ли стандартное решение или он просто заменяет `select()` и многопоточность нужно реализовывать самому?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все оказывается до банальности просто, достаточно использовать флаг EPOLLONESHOT в `epoll_ctl()` и сокет будет выдаваться один раз.