# Высоконагруженное тестирование сервера

Tags: linux, сокет, epoll

Я написал сервер с двумя реализациями пула: `epoll()` и моей реализацией на `select()`, и, как выясняется, моя реализация работает быстрее, что в теории должно быть бредом, да и в моем восприятии епул должен работать быстрее. Так почему это не так?

Итак, я тестирую сервер, который считывает данные из сокета, находит HTTP заголовок и отвечает

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: StormServer

Not Found
```

Для тестирования сервера я использую свою программу http_load, которая в 90 потоках подключается к серверу, посылает

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1
```

считывает ответ и закрывает соединение. И посылает эти запросы в течении 10 секунд, после чего подводится итог.

Результаты измерений, количество обработанных подключений в секунду:

Мой poll на `select()`: 5178, 5086, 4989, 5011, 4970.

Стандартный epoll: 4825, 4751, 4800, 4799, 4798.

Еще тестирование в течении минуты: 4767, 4771 - мой poll и 4602, 4552 - epoll.

Чем/как еще тестировать сервер? Есть специальные программы? Возможно стоит установить больше соединений? Или передавать больше данных?

---

UPD. Отчет тестирования ab.

- http://pastebin.com/eC8Brk6D и http://pastebin.com/9TbycRnb - на ab -kc 10 -t 60 побеждает epoll.
- http://pastebin.com/9XeZf8TT и http://pastebin.com/rz2iWUxB - на ab -kc 100 -t 60 -n 100000 epoll тормозит.

Comment: есть стандартный ab (apache benchmark). Он умеет тестить http  запросы вдоль и впоперек. Попробуйте его.

А вот почему одна реализация бысрее другой - нужно смотреть в код. Всякое может быть.

Comment: тоже написал серверок... хочу потестить... можно попробывать вашей программой http_load?

Comment: Погонял ab, вроде как при низкой нагрузке epoll быстрее, а при высокой тормозит. Ссылки на отчеты в вопросе.   @sitev_ru, возьми ab, она тоже неплохо тестирует.

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то делал подобные измерения. Процессы-потоки клиентов и сервер запускаются на одном и том же хосте (да, это существенный недостаток). В общем-то тестируется количество соединений (данных передается мало).

Можете посмотреть код на http://pastebin.com/vbMLKhrB , транслируйте `gcc conn.c -pthreads`.

Сейчас уже точно не помню, как ей пользоваться, но там есть что-то вроде help-а (по `./a.out -h`). Насколько смог быстро соорентироваться -- при указании количества клиентских потоков (тех, что делают connect и создают нагрузку) нужно обязательно указать порт сервера. Например:

```
./a.out -T2 -C4 12345 16
```

запускает 4 клиентских процесса в которых запускаются 16 потоков (по 4 на процесс), они соединяются с портом 12345 сервера (это отдельный процесс, запускается тут же автоматически), который обслуживает соединения в потоке из пула (пул из 2-х потоков).

```
./a.out -t -s 12345 32
```

запустит  сервер, который использует select и обрабатывает каждое соединение в новом потоке, а клиент из одного процесса создает 32 нагрузочных потока

```
./a.out -y
```

коннекты от 4-х клиентских потоков (это по умолчанию -- клиент из одного процесса и 4-х потоков) асинхронно обрабатываются сервером, используя epoll, как для получения новых соединений, так и фрагментов данных.

Ну, комбинаций аргументов может быть много.

Если заинтересуетесь (и начнете экспериментировать), то наверное разберетесь. Тогда дайте знать (упомините @avp в комментарии и тогда придет нотификация), я освежу свою память и мы сможем пообсуждать эти темы (но только уже вечером в воскресенье или в понедельник).